# Где взять полный список существующих тегов html

Tags: html, css, браузер, теги, спецификация

Пытаюсь изучить HTML. Но в интернете куча устаревшей информации, что просто не могу понять, какие теги можно использовать, а какие устарели или просто не рекомендуются, еще путаница с html5. Причем в разных источниках пишут разную инфу на эту тему.  Соответственно, у меня возник такой вопрос.

> 1) Есть ли где-то список всех существующих html тегов и css?
>
> 2) Есть ли список всех актуальных тегов (неустаревших)?
>
> 3) Есть ли список всех рекомендуемых тегов (т.е. тег может быть
>   неустаревшим, но его использовать не рекомендуется или просто уже
>   никто не использует, потому что неудобный)?
>
> 4) Есть ли список всех тегов браузеров, где можно посмотреть, например
>   для мозиллы? - где-то слышал, что вроде как браузеры не обращают
>   внимания на официальную спецификацию html и в них заложены в т.ч. теги
>   которых и подавно нет в официальной спецификации

Answer (score 1):

- [Список HTML меток](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element)
- [Список общих правил CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference)
- [Список правил CSS для Mozilla Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Mozilla_Extensions)
- [Список правил CSS для WebKit-браузеров (Chrome, Opera, Safari)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Webkit_Extensions)

Comment: А еще это можно добавить это: [w3.org/TR/html-markup/elements.html](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/elements.html); и это: [html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/indices.html#elements-3](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/indices.html#elements-3); и ещё незаменимый HTMLBook: [webref.ru/html](https://webref.ru/html), [webref.ru/css](https://webref.ru/css).

Comment: webref.ru - там не все теги есть.
w3.org/TR/html-markup/elements.html; - ссылка на старую версию, неактуально